# semantic ui build how to put together this item

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, semantic-ui

Alright so attached is a picture of an element that I want to build with semantic ui but after spending hours trying to figure it out, I just cant make it work.

Any ideas? In [image]JSFiddle would be the answer that I am looking for.

```
<div class='items'>
  <div class='item'>
    <div class='ui buttons'>
      <button class='ui labeled button'>
        <a class='ui basic label'>File name</a>
        <div class='ui progress bottom attached'>
        <div class='bar'></div>
      </div>
      </button>
      <button class='ui basic icon button'>
        <i class='sync icon'></i>
      </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style='border: 2px red solid; width: auto; padding: 0px;'>
  <div style='display: inline-block;'>
    <p>Filename</p>
    <progress max=100 value=20></progress>
  </div>
  <div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;' class='ui basic icon button'>
    <i class='ui icon sync'></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code so far and let us know what you've tried and what issues you've run into. Stack Overflow is for getting help on code you've written, not for asking others to write code for you.

Comment: @Keara If you're going to vote it down then give an explanation!

Comment: Explanation was: please post your code. Now that there's code, people can take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I think it would still be easier for others to understand if you give a detailed explanation of what problems you are seeing. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Keara please become familiar with stack overflow rules. This is the rule about voting down an question "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." Link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @miguel i think what your looking for is css grid see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp if you need more explanation on how to apply it let me know but i think you will figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, I always appreciate being able to understand S.O. rules and conventions better, and I did review the rule you linked. I didn't downvote the question lightly; I felt that the question as you posted it was not answerable, and needed to be improved before anyone would be able to answer it. With code, it's at least answerable, if still a bit unclear. I hope someone is able to give a good answer.

Comment: @BobbyAxe that's not what I'm looking for. I want to use the semantic-ui because of theming and also because of all the icons, animations, and much more that I can do to an element once I create it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is semantically wrong to insert a `div` inside a `button`, so phrasing content is expected, see [HTML button element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) and [HTML Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/content-models.html#phrasing-content). You will need to remove the div's inside the `<button class='ui labeled button'>` or do a different approach.

You can achieve the desire result using flexbox, see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Or better you can apply semantic-ui GRID: https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

```css
.progress-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.progress-wrapper .ui.progress{
    margin-bottom: 0 !Important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div class='items'>
  <div class='item'>
       <div class="progress-wrapper">
          <div class="progress-wrap">
          <a class='ui basic label'>File name</a>
          <div class='ui progress'>
            <div class='bar' style="width: 12%;">
              <div class="progress">12%</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class='ui basic icon button'>
          <i class='sync icon'></i>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to share my updated code but it still wasn't what I needed....it was going to be an update but you already answer the question with exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man!